# Exception on Monitor.Exit in C#

Tags: c#, synchronization

This is a large multi-threaded project (which I didn't write) that I am fixing. The application hangs on some locks which I am tracking down.

I went through and replaced all the "lock" statements with `Monitor.TryEnter` so I could set a wait period. I am occasionally getting an exception with the `Monitor.Exit`.

The original style was

```
private List<myClass> _myVar= new List<myClass>();

if (_myVar != null)
{
    lock (_myVar)
    {
        _myVar = newMyVar; // Where newMyVar is another List<myClass>
    }
}
```

I replaced all my locks like above with:

```
if (_myVar != null)
{
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(_myVar, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), ref lockTaken);
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            _myVar = newMyVar; // Where newMyVar is another List<myClass>
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(_myVar);
    }
}
```

The exception I am getting is

> SynchronizationLockException Object synchronization method was called
>   from an unsynchronized block of code

. If this is true, why doesn't the original lock statement also throw an exception?

Would it be safe to put the `Monitor.Exit` in a try catch and just ignore it if there is an exception?

Comment: Are you by any chance doing any `await`ing inside your new custom made locks?

Comment: Are you sure that it is an exit which is throwing, and not, say a pulse?

Comment: As mentioned above, check `// do some stuff with _myVar` code for `await`. For your question: most probably not, do not ignore it, something is not right and you need to find and fix it. The code you've provided looks fine.

Comment: Sergey is right: **do not ignore this under any circumstances**.  Something is **seriously wrong**.

Comment: Nope, no await operations.  None in the program at all, actually

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Is changing all the locks to locks that time out an attempt to *diagnose* the problem or to *fix* the problem?  This is a problematic technique either way, but its hard to give you advice when its unclear what you're doing.

Comment: Actually, the "do some stuff" is simply setting a List<> to another List<>.  I can't do that, can I?  I should clear the list, and add new elements - not change the list pointer itself.  Am I correct?  (I am editing my question)

Comment: Ah, your edit makes all the difference. **That original code is completely and utterly wrong**. It will never work reliably. Imagine that you go into the bathroom, you lock the door, and while you're in there you *build a second door that you leave open*, and then you wonder why you sometimes end up with two people in the bathroom.  **Never lock a variable that you are modifying in the lock**. That's a completely crazy and wrong thing to do.

Comment: xD you're trying to release lock on another reference (not the one you used to  lock on). Like in `Object o = new Object(); System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(o);`

Comment: Whoever wrote this "big multithreaded program" did not understand even the most basic facts about locks, and it is probably a huge mess as a result. The fact that it is not immediately apparent what the problem is means that you don't understand locks well enough to fix it correctly.

Comment: The popular pattern is to use some independent private dummy objects that are initialized once on construction for synchronization. In class `private Object myLockForSection1 = new Object();` then when you enter "Section1" in method, you lock on this reference `lock(myLockForSection1) { /* work */ }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be very clear why you are getting the exception in your new code. **If the lock is taken then the object that is unlocked is not the object that was locked**. Locks take an *object*, not a *variable*.  The correct translation of the *deeply wrong* original code is

```
// THIS CODE IS COMPLETELY WRONG; DO NOT USE IT
if (_myVar != null) 
{
    bool lockTaken = false;
    var locker = _myVar;
    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(locker, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), ref lockTaken);
        if (lockTaken) 
        {
            _myVar = newMyVar; // where newMyVar is another List<myClass>
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(locker);
    }
}
```

Which will not throw on exit, but *is still completely wrong*.

**Never** lock on the contents of a variable and then *mutate the variable*; *every subsequent lock will lock on a different object!*  So you have no mutual exclusion.

And **never** lock on a public object! If that list leaks out anywhere then *other wrong code can be locking on that list in an unexpected order*, which means deadlocks -- which is the original symptom you are diagnosing.

The correct practice for locking on a field is to create a private readonly object field used *only* as a locker, and used *every time* the field is accessed.  That way you know that (1) the field is always accessed under the same lock, no matter its value, and (2) the lock object is used only for locking that field, and not for locking something else. That ensures mutual exclusion and prevents deadlocks.

The fact that someone wrote a large multithreaded program without understanding the most basic facts about locks means that it is almost certainly a complete mess of hard-to-find bugs. The fact that this wasn't immediately obvious upon reading the code means that you don't have enough knowledge of threading to fix the problems correctly. You're going to need to either find an expert on this stuff who can help you, or gain at least a minimal working knowledge of correct practices.

I cannot emphasize enough that **this is hard stuff.** Programs with multiple threads of control in them are extremely difficult to write correctly on modern hardware; many of the things you believe are guaranteed by the language are only guaranteed in single threaded programs.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.  Yes, I am gaining experience with multi-threading now, rather quickly.