# Broken lock strategy - analysis and correction

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I'm asking this primarily as a sanity check: In a C# (8.0) application I've got this bit of code, which spuriously fails with an "object is not synchronized" exception from `Monitor.pulse()` (I've omitted irrelevant code for clarity):

```
// vanilla multiple-producer single-consumer queue stuff:

private Queue<Message> messages = new Queue<Message>();

private void ConsumerThread () {
    Queue<Message> myMessages = new Queue<Message>();
    while (...) {
        lock (messages) {
            // wait
            while (messages.Count == 0)
                Monitor.Wait(messages);
            // swap
            (messages, myMessages) = (myMessages, messages);
        }
        // process
        while (myMessages.Count > 0)
            DoStuff(myMessages.Dequeue());
    }
}

public void EnqueueMessage (...) {
    Message message = new Message(...);
    lock (messages) {
        messages.Enqueue(message);
        Monitor.Pulse(messages);
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to C# and also I was stressed when I wrote that. Now I am reviewing that code to fix the exception and I'm immediately raising an eyebrow at the fact that I reassigned `messages` inside the consumer's lock.

I looked around and found [Is it bad to overwrite a lock object if it is the last statement in the lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853485/is-it-bad-to-overwrite-a-lock-object-if-it-is-the-last-statement-in-the-lock), which validates my raised eyebrow.

---

However, I still don't have a lot of confidence (inexperience + stress), so, just to confirm: **Is the following analysis of why this is broken correct?**

If the following happens, in this order:

1. Stuff happens to be in the queue.
2. Consumer thread locks `messages` (and will skip wait loop).
3. `EnqueueMessage` tries to lock `messages`, waits for lock.
4. Consumer thread swaps `messages` and `myMessages`, releases lock.
5. `EnqueueMessage` takes lock.
6. `EnqueueMessage` adds item to `messages` and calls `Monitor.pulse(messages)` except `messages` isn't the same object that it locked in step (3), since it was swapped out from under us in (4). Possible consequences include:

   - Calling `Monitor.Pulse` on a non-locked object (what used to be `myMessages`) -- hence the aforementioned exception.
   - Enqueueing to the wrong queue and the consequences of that.
   - Even weirder stuff if the consumer thread manages to complete another full loop cycle while `EnqueueMessage` is still somewhere in its `lock{}`.

Right? I'm pretty sure that's right, it feels very basic, but I just want to confirm because I'm completely burnt out right now.

---

Then, whether that's correct or not: **Does the following proposed fix make sense?**

It seems to me like the fix is super simple: Instead of using `messages` as the monitor object, just use some dedicated dummy object that won't be changed:

```
private readonly object messagesLock = new object();
private Queue<Message> messages = new Queue<Message>();

private void ConsumerThread () {
    Queue<Message> myMessages = new Queue<Message>();
    while (...) {
        lock (messagesLock) {
            while (messages.Count == 0) 
                Monitor.Wait(messagesLock);
            (messages, myMessages) = (myMessages, messages);
        }
    }
    ...
}

public void EnqueueMessage (...) {
    ...;
    lock (messagesLock) {
        messages.Enqueue(...);
        Monitor.Pulse(messagesLock);
    }
}
```

Where the intent is to avoid any issues caused by swapping out the lock object in strange places.

And that should work... right?

Comment: @Renat actually the `lock` works with `Wait`/`Pulse` [just fine](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_How_to_Use_Wait_and_Pulse).

Comment: JasonC why live in the edge and waste brainpower trying to diagnose obscure race conditions, instead of doing the obvious, use a dedicated locker object, and preserve your sanity for more important things?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I agree.

Comment: @JasonC Your analysis of the issue looks correct

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated. The solution seems to check out, too (separate lock object). Looking at it with a much clearer head today.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody uses `Queue` in multi-threading since .NET 2 probably 16 yrs ago (correct me if I am wrong with dates).

it is trivial with concurrent collections.

```
BlockingColleciton<Message> myMessages = new BlockingColleciton<Message>();

private void ConsumerThread () {
    while (...) 
    {
        var message = myMessages.Take();
    }
    ...
}

public void EnqueueMessage (Message msg) {
    ...;
    myMessages.Add(msg);
}
```

Comment: OH MAN what a game changer for me. Thank you!!